# Pack non-NA values up in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there an easy way to "pack" all non-NA values upwards in a data frame or data table in R? For example I have:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
   1    NA    NA   1.2  
   2    NA    NA   1.3
   3   1.4    NA    NA
   4   1.5    NA    NA
   5    NA   2.3    NA
   6    NA   1.4    NA
```

Result would be:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
   1   1.4   2.3   1.2  
   2   1.5   1.4   1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sapply` :

```
tmp <- sapply(df, na.omit)
data.frame(sapply(tmp, `[`, 1:min(lengths(tmp))))

#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    1  1.4  2.3  1.2
#2    2  1.5  1.4  1.3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = c(NA, NA, 1.4, 1.5, NA, NA), 
    col3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.3, 1.4), col4 = c(1.2, 1.3, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```